# how to draw rectangle on java applet using mouse drag event

Tags: java, applet, drawing, awt

i am using java.
i want to draw rectangle based on mousedrag event. if user dragging the mouse, then the rectangle on the applet should increase or decrease basing on current mouse coordinates.
i have the following code.

in the following code i am using [b]SelectionArea[/b] class which extends a canvas on which i am performing drawing operation. i am using [b]image[/b] variable in this class for double buffering to reduce flickering and to save the applet's previous state(i.e drawing content of applet)

but the code is working fine if i draw first rectangle. if i start to draw second rectangle the previously drawn rectangle  is disappearing. i want the previously drawn rectangle to be on the screen

can any one tell me how to solve this.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.event.*;

/* 
 * This displays a framed area.  When the user drags within
 * the area, this program displays a rectangle extending from
 * where the user first pressed the mouse button to the current
 * cursor location.
 */

public class RectangleDemo extends Applet {
SelectionArea drawingPanel;
Label label;

public void init() {
    GridBagLayout gridBag = new GridBagLayout();
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    setLayout(gridBag);

    drawingPanel = new SelectionArea(this);
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    c.weighty = 1.0;
    c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER; //end row
    gridBag.setConstraints(drawingPanel, c);
    add(drawingPanel);

    label = new Label("Drag within the framed area.");
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.weightx = 1.0;
    c.weighty = 0.0;
    gridBag.setConstraints(label, c);
    add(label);
    drawingPanel.setVisible(true);

    validate();
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    drawingPanel.repaint();
}

public void update(Graphics g){
    paint(g);
}
```

}

```
class SelectionArea extends Canvas implements ActionListener, MouseListener,    MouseMotionListener{
Rectangle currentRect;
RectangleDemo controller;
//for double buffering
Image image;
Graphics offscreen;
public SelectionArea(RectangleDemo controller) {
    super();
    this.controller = controller;
    addMouseListener(this);
    addMouseMotionListener(this);        
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
    repaintoffscreen();
}

public void repaintoffscreen(){
    image = createImage(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
    offscreen = image.getGraphics();
    Dimension d = getSize();
    if(currentRect != null){
        Rectangle box = getDrawableRect(currentRect, d);            

        //Draw the box outline.
        offscreen.drawRect(box.x, box.y, box.width - 1, box.height - 1);  
        //repaint();
    }
}

public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {}
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me){ }
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me){}
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me){}

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {        
    currentRect = new Rectangle(me.getX(), me.getY(), 0, 0);
    repaintoffscreen();        
}

public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
    System.out.println("here in dragged()");
    currentRect.setSize(me.getX() - currentRect.x, me.getY() - currentRect.y);
    repaintoffscreen();    
    repaint();
}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
    currentRect.setSize(me.getX() - currentRect.x, me.getY() - currentRect.y);
    repaintoffscreen();  
    repaint();
}

public void update(Graphics g){
    paint(g);
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
}

Rectangle getDrawableRect(Rectangle originalRect, Dimension drawingArea) {
    int x = originalRect.x;
    int y = originalRect.y;
    int width = originalRect.width;
    int height = originalRect.height;

    //Make sure rectangle width and height are positive.
    if (width < 0) {
        width = 0 - width;
        x = x - width + 1;
        if (x < 0) {
            width += x;
            x = 0;
        }
    }
    if (height < 0) {
        height = 0 - height;
        y = y - height + 1;
        if (y < 0) {
            height += y;
            y = 0;
        }
    }

    //The rectangle shouldn't extend past the drawing area.
    if ((x + width) > drawingArea.width) {
        width = drawingArea.width - x;
    }
    if ((y + height) > drawingArea.height) {
        height = drawingArea.height - y;
    }

    return new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
}
```

}

also if i run this code on full screen mode then i am seeing that the rectangle is appering on screen only after i released the mouse. but i want the rectangle to be on the screen while dragging the mouse and it should change it's dimension according to the current mouse coordinates.
can any one help me pls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

homework?

basically what you need to do is:

1. on mouse down keep the mouse-down coordinates and repaint
2. on mouse move keep current mouse coordinates and repaint
3. on mouse up, nullify the mouse-down coordinates to indicate there is no rect, and repaint.
4. on paint, draw background and then rect between mousedown and cur-mouse coordinates.

if you don't want to keep a background image, you can do a trick with the Graphics xor function, drawing the same rect twice will erase the old rect, so you can use it to restore the old image straight on the graphics object.

Edit: code xor usage sample:

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
   g.setXORMode(Color.black);
   // draw old rect if there is one. this will erase it
   // draw new rect, this will draw xored
   g.setDrawMode(); // restore normal draw mode
}
```

Xor has the an interesting property:

```
xor(xor(x)) = x
```

so xoring the same pixel twice restores it's original color.

Comment: thanks omry,
this is not an homework. ok can u give me a code sample on how to work with Grphics xOR function.
thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple issues that need to be addressed.

First, regarding only one rectangle can be drawn, this is due to the design of your program. In your code, whenever the `repaintoffscreen` method is called, the `currectRect` field is used to draw a rectangle. However, there is no provision to keep holding onto rectangles which were made in the past.

One way to keep a hold of past rectangles would be perhaps to make another field which is, for example, a `List<Rectangle>` which is used to store past rectangles. Then, when the mouse is released, `add` the current rectangle to that list.

Then, in order for all rectangles, `currentRect` and past rectangles to appear, `repaintoffscreen` will need to not only perform `getDrawableRect` and `offscreen.drawRect` using the `currentRect` but also with the past rectangles which are stored in the `List<Rectangle>`. (Hint, use a `for` loop to iterate through the list.)

Second, regarding the rectangle not appearing until after releasing the mouse button, rather than using the `mouseDragged` method, maybe using the `mouseMoved` method along with a check to see that the mouse button is depressed may be a workaround. (I think I've also had trouble dealing with the `mouseDragged` method in the past.)

The [`MouseEvent`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html) passed into the `mouseMoved` method can be used to check if a button is depressed by the [`getButton`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html#getButton()) method:

```
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
{
    // Check if button1 is pressed.
    if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1)
    {
        // Perform sizing of rectangle and off-screen drawing, and repaint.
    }
}
```

Comment: hi coobird,
thanks for reply. i want to extend my code to draw other symbols like oval,line also. so can i have a common object that i can store in the list? can u tell me what fields that i can put in the object so that i can use this object for drawing previously drawn symbols in the repaintoffscreenmethod().
thanks

Answer (score 0):

My question was about create a select rectangle invert mouse click position, but, in the end I got make this with this method:

```
...     //to set the selection area
    private int iniSelX;
    private int iniSelY;
    private int endSelX;
    private int endSelY;

    private JPanel myJPanel = new JPanel() {

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());

            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.drawLine(260, 5, 260, 260);

            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);

            //verify if go draw the rectangle
            if (iniSelX != 0 || endSelX != 0) {
                boolean revertX = iniSelX < endSelX;
                boolean revertY = iniSelY < endSelY;

                //Simple way
                //g.drawRect(iniSelX, iniSelY, endSelX - iniSelX, endSelY - iniSelY);

                //reverse way
                g.drawRect(revertX ? iniSelX : endSelX, revertY ? iniSelY : endSelY,
                        revertX ? endSelX - iniSelX : iniSelX - endSelX, revertY ? endSelY - iniSelY : iniSelY - endSelY);
            }
        }
    }; ...
        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {

            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent m) {
                //update selection area
                endSelX = m.getX();
                endSelY = m.getY();

                repaint();
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent m) {
                repaint();
            }
        });

        addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

 ...
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
               //start  drawing the selection
                iniSelX = e.getX() - 15;
                iniSelY = e.getY() - 20;
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                //start  drawing the selection
                iniSelX = 0;
                iniSelY = 0;
                endSelX = 0;
                endSelY = 0;
            }

...
        });

    }

    public void log() {
        System.out.println("iniSelX" + iniSelX);
        System.out.println("iniSelY" + iniSelY);
        System.out.println("endSelX" + endSelX);
        System.out.println("endSelY" + endSelY);
    } ...
```

I hope this is useful.