# How to draw a rectangle around the mouse cursor in Java?

Tags: java, swing

I had made one module in my project on which user can draw anything using a pencil.

Now I want to create an eraser for that drawing module, so I need it so that as soon as the user clicks on that eraser button then around my mouse cursor I want a little rectangle shape around it, so the user can use it to erase some parts in the drawing.

How to do this? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of drawing a rectangle around the cursor, I would suggest to set a custom curser for the selected tool.

Just to show the API, (not tested) something like that sould work.

```
Image cursorImg = new ImageIcon("rectangle.gif").getImage();        
Point hotspot = new Point(0, 0);     // should be set to the center of your rectangle    
Cursor cursor = getToolkit().createCustomCursor(cursorImg, hotspot, "cursorname");

YourComponent.setCursor( cursor );
```

EDIT:

I have to add that getToolkit() is a method of [java.awt.Component](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html)

Comment: but there is one extra feature in my app. from where people can increase the size of eraser...
so then what to?

Comment: @Nitz in this case I would draw a rectangle in XOR mode

Comment: @Nitz see i.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/880753/how-to-draw-rectangle-on-java-applet-using-mouse-drag-event or google "java draw rect xor example"