# Why can't drag a rectangle on canvas using the XOR globalCompositeOperation?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have created a lot of rectangles on the canvas. Now I am about to drag one of them to move on the canvas.How to do this? I find a solution:clear the canvas and redraw it again. yes ,it works. But if there are 10,000 rectangles ,I need a lot of time to redraw them.
I am a C++ programmer. I know how to realize this function using XOR . I find a Java solution at [how to draw rectangle on java applet using mouse drag event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880753/how-to-draw-rectangle-on-java-applet-using-mouse-drag-event) . Why the Canvas' XOR don't work as I want? Are there some other methods to realize my ideal? thanks.

Comment: I need more suggestion,thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a hidden image containing the original canvas image (before drag) and then redraw using the saved image, so there is only one draw operation on each move.

```
//canvas = your canvas element
//Save the image before drag
var img = new Image();
img.src = canvas.toDataURL();

//On drag, redraw the saved image
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EDT44/1/).

---

Or, if you know the width and height of the rectangle, you can redraw only the area where the rectangle previously was:

```
//Store the rectangle's coordinates
var rectCoords = {x: 0, y: 0};
//The rectangle's size
var rectSize = {width: 50, height: 50};
//Create a canvas element
var savedCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
savedCanvas.width = canvas.width + rectSize.width;
savedCanvas.height = canvas.height + rectSize.height;
var ctxSaved = savedCanvas.getContext("2d");
```

Before dragging:

```
//Draw the entire canvas onto the saved canvas
ctxSaved.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);
//Store your coordinates for the redraw
rectCoords.x = "Your coordinate";
rectCoords.y = "Your coordinate";
```

When you have to redraw the rectangle, you just have to do:

```
//Draw original image only in the area where the rectangle was drawn
ctx.drawImage(savedCanvas, rectCoords.x, rectCoords.y, rectSize.width, rectSize.height,
rectCoords.x, rectCoords.y, rectSize.width, rectSize.height);
//Store your coordinates for the next redraw
rectCoords.x = "Your coordinate";
rectCoords.y = "Your coordinate";
```

Please see the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EDT44/4/) for a working demo.

Note: this will not work if you have images drawn on the canvas from another domain, due to security concerns.

Comment: drawImage will cost a lot of CPU ,but it's better than redraw all of the shape.

Comment: You can also only redraw a specific portion of the canvas (where the rectangle was) - this should reduce CPU consumption.

Comment: Yes. This is what I am doing.But the algorithm will be very complexly.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way how to control only single element on Canvas.
When you draw something to canvas, API will just write "pixels" to canvas and forget everythings about it.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't try to fool around with XOR to get it working, its not really suitable, because the "before" and "after" of drawing both include the rectangle you want to move.

To get started along this line, take a look at my [tutorials on the matter](http://simonsarris.com/blog/140-canvas-moving-selectable-shapes).

Comment: Yes,your demo is ok.But it is Inefficient. I have a lot of shapes needing to redraw.I can't refresh the canvas by time. It will make the CPU 100%.